# Laravel Spatie Get All Permissions with Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, permissions, laravel-permission

everybody!
I am using Laravel Spatie Permission Package.
And I can get user's all assigned permissions like this.

```
$user->getAllPermissions()
```

However, I want to get all permissions with eager loading.
Maybe like this.

```
$users = User::with('getAllPermissions')->get();
```

But this didn't worked.

I tried

```
$users = user::with('permissions')->get();
```

But query counts were same result with

```
$users = user::get();
```

So `$user->getAllPermissions()` is already eager loaded query?

Or is there any eager loaded query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a pretty tricky thing to do to get all permission with user lists.

```
$users = user::with('permissions')->get();
```

this will provide permissions model with users list. In this way, you will get only permissions assigned to a user. But the user has a role then role permission will not be added.

But `$user->getAllPermissions();` function will give you all permission related to user role and permission. But we need all permission with the users' list.

I created a Mutators function to get permissions with the user list.

```
public function getPermissionAttribute()
{
    return $this->getAllPermissions();
}
```

now You can append in your model

```
protected $appends = [
    'permission'
]
```

Now to avoid recursive query (aka n+1 query problem, to avoid execute for each user one query), write your user query like this

```
$users = user::with(['permissions', 'roles'])->get();
```

Or Add in your user model

```
protected $with =[
   'permissions',
    'roles'
]
```

I think this will help you.